# Capturing random images

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I think everything speaks for itself in the image below.  I'm not sure how to write the code to acomplish it.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can store 36 images (or path to iamges) in the collection and when you click on Add button, it chooses random number from 1-36 and load that image to the labels accordingly.

Here are the steps:

- Store 36 image filepaths in array Array (i.e.  'image1.jpg' and etc)
- Use  `Int((36 * Rnd) + 1)` to generate random number between 1 and 36 (you will need to run this 3 times)
- Create Image control (not label, while you can use label to show some text). and then assign  Image.Picture properties to the filepath

Comment: Thanks, I know just a little about vba, but not that much.  How would I write the code using the variable names I have stated above?